# sending text output to a window

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been writing a small text-adventure type game using Python 3.x and Windows 7.

I currently just throw all the output to the console like this:

```
print("-------------------------")
print ("\nYou walk into a large room with a low ceiling.")
```

I was wondering if there is a way to open up a window and have all the text and user-interactivity inside that window?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to open up a second console window during gameplay, or are you interested in your game opening up the initial console window?

Comment: Have you looked into the [curses library](http://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/curses.html)? That might be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the Tkinter module that ships with Python. http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter